# Capistrano mkdir permission denied

Tags: ubuntu, deployment, capistrano, sudo, vps

When I run `cap production deploy` I get `cannot create directory ‘/var/www/application/repo’: Permission denied`.

So far I've created deploy user like:

```
adduser deploy
adduser deploy sudo
```

and I use this user in Capistrano.

Indeed, when I log to `deploy@my.vps.ip` I don't have `sudo` permission by default, every time  I need to enable it explicitly like `sudo su`.

I see two possible solutions:

1. Enable sudo in Capistrano
2. Enable sudo in Ubuntu

Unfortunately I don't know how to do neither of them.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

By default Capistrano 3 deploys to `/var/www` which is not writable by `deploy` user. You need to change the ownership of `/var/www` to `deploy` user using the following command.

```
sudo chown deploy:deploy /var/www/
```

After this, you should be able to deploy your app without permission error.

Comment: If someone is using Amazon EC2 ```sudo chown ec2-user:ec2-user /var/www/```

Comment: You most likely will need to use -R so that all subdirectories are owned by deploy user:


`sudo chown -R deploy:deploy /var/www/`

Answer (score 5):

Credit to Bob Roberts.

I think this should be an answer as its easy to miss your comment. I know I missed it few times.

```
sudo chown -R deploy:deploy /var/www/
```

or whatever your username is

```
sudo chown -R username:username /var/www/
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error here, following the good tutorial of [GoRails](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzEEfAj45zw) "Deploy Ruby on Rails To Production in 2019", where he create a user "deploy" and set to deploy the app in "home/deploy". 
Don't forget that you have to use the username created on the server. 
So deploy's directory is "home/USERNAME".

Comment: Please some explanation as links may die one day.