# Capistrano configuration leading to mkdir permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

Upon execution a `deploy` to a server for a specific application, the process interrupts  at this stage

```
 DEBUG [88db4789] Command: ( export RBENV_ROOT="$HOME/.rbenv" RBENV_VERSION="2.3.4" ; /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /var/www/v4/shared /var/www/v4/releases )

 DEBUG [88db4789]   mkdir:

 DEBUG [88db4789]   cannot create directory ‘/var/www’

 DEBUG [88db4789]   : Permission denied
```

*Note: this occurring only for this particular application.  Another application that deploys to the same server processes past this stage*

I have attempted to change ownership [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24470520/capistrano-mkdir-permission-denied), but that fails

```
chown: cannot access ‘/var/www/’: No such file or directory
```

so I am led to believe a configuration issue is the culprit.  Aside from the environment data

```
server 'xx.xxx.xxx.xxx', user: 'deploy', roles: %w{db web app}
```

where have I missed something?

Answer (score 0):

Your server instance does not have the folder `/var/www`, so you can do manually by ssh to that server as user `deploy` then try to make the folder yourself.

I think it again will fail because of your `deploy` user does not have the rights to `/var` folder. Try to change the ownership following the guide you have to do so.

Answer (score 0):

While yeuem1vannam's answer is valid, this use case actually had a different problem in the `deploy.rb` file.  The path specified there had an error in the user name, thus the permission error to create the folder upon deploy.